# ¿Cómo abrir una vista previa de una imagen guardada en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Tengo una tabla y en esta tabla un campo donde se guarda el nombre de la imagen, por ejemplo imagen.jpg, lo que necesito es poder verla en un módulo pero no sé como hacerlo. He intentado esto

```
<div class="col-md-6 b-r">

<!--<label>Imagen principal del auto</label>
{!! Form::file('rutaImagenPrincipal') !!}
        <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
        <label>Caracteristicas (imagen)</label>
{!! Form::file('rutaImagenCaracte') !!}
        -->
    {!! Html::image('storage/app/'.$auto->rutaImagenCaracte.'','',array('class'=>'img-responsive')) !!}
    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline" value="REGISTRAR">
    </div>
    <div class="hr-line-dashed"></div>
</div>
```

Y sí me da el url de donde se encuentra mi imagen, pero no me abre, me aparece error como si no lo encontrara. Espero su ayuda, gracias les dejo la imagen de donde están mis imágenes alojadas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Haz mirado con el inspector que ruta te está pintando ?

Comment: he visto en el error y me sale correcto el url, y cuando pongo el url en el navegador tampoco me abre

Comment: y que url te arroja ??

Comment: http://motorcisne.com/storage/app/Captura.PNG

Comment: extraño, haz revisado que depronto no sea algo de estilos ?

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es enlazar el directorio `storage/app/public` a la carpeta `public` del proyecto. Para hacerlo ejecuta en la consola el siguiente comando:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Y luego ya puedes poner la imagen:

```
{!! Html::image('storage/'.$auto->rutaImagenCaracte.'','',array('class'=>'img-responsive')) !!}
```

Donde `$auto->rutaImagenCaracte` es el nombre de la imagen (nombreImagen.jpg)

**Edito**

Para poder usar el helper HTML hay que instalar Laravel Collective. esto se hace a través de composer.
Se modifica el composer.json

```
"require": {
    "laravelcollective/html": "~5.0"
}
```

Se ejecuta en el terminal el comando

```
composer update
```

Se añade un nuevo provider en `providers` de config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    'Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
    // ...
  ],
```

Y finalmente se añade el àlias`

```
'aliases' => [
    // ...
      'Form' => 'Collective\Html\FormFacade',
      'Html' => 'Collective\Html\HtmlFacade',
    // ...
  ],
```

Comment: Pues yo pruebo eso y me sale este error: Class 'Html' not found (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\flora\resources\views\vegetal\index.blade.php)

Comment: en config/app.php, en la clave `aliases` hay que tener: `'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class` y tener instalado `laravelcollective`, porque en caso contrario devuelve ese error.

Comment: vale, he instalado 'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class. Ahora me queda lo de laravelcollective, que no se como se hace.

Comment: Editada la respuesta con la información necesaria. Pero puedes seguir usando los tags html

Comment: Ya consegui importar lo que sugieres. Aunque lo mio esta chungo, pues he probado incluso usar <img> con imagenes fijas (en vez de poner de src una variable pongo una ruta fija) y tampoco se muestra la imagen.

Comment: No sé, haz una captura de la estructura de carpetas...

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73145/discussion-between-pedro-prada-and-miguel-alparez).

Comment: Hare una nueva pregunta pidiendo algo más sencillo y así vamos tirando.

Answer (score 0):

yo para subir imagenes al proyecto hago lo siguiente, creo una carpeta de fotos en public ej: public/fotos es este directorio guardo todas las fotos que se suben.

Para guardar las imagenes en esta carpeta se hace lo siguiente

```
$image = $request->file('foto'); //imagen que viene en el request
$destino = public_path() . "/fotos/";
$image->move($destino, $image->getClientOriginalName()); //lo guardas con el nombre de la imagen
```

y para poder acceder a esta imagen haces uso de assets(), ej:

```
<img src={{assets('fotos/img.png')}}>
```

espero te sea de ayuda.

lo que hace la directiva assets es ubicarte directamente en tu carpeta public