# Ver imagenes almacenadas en una vista de Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Veran, tengo una tabla de plantas la cual tiene las siguientes propiedades:

```
Schema::create('plantas', function (Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre'); // Nombre de la planta.
            $table->string('tamaño'); // Clasifica segun si es arbol, arbusto o hierba. 
            $table->string('flor'); // Si tiene o no flor.
            $table->string('hoja'); // Si es de hoja caduca o perenne.
            $table->text('descripcion'); // Caracteristicas del vegetal.
            $table->string('foto')->nullable(); // Esta variable sera utilizada para almacenar fotos. Es opcional.
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Tengo que crear una vista en la cual se muestre las caracteristicas de cada planta, incluido una foto de la planta (en caso de que la tenga).
Aqui muestro la vista:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div align="center" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h1 class="text-center text-mute"> {{ __("Plantas") }} </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @Logged()
                    <a href="formulario/plantas">Crear una nueva planta</a>
                    @include('partials.errors')
                @else
                    <p style="color:#0000FF">Para poner insertar nuevas plantas tienes que iniciar sesión</p>
                @endLogged
            </div>
        </div>

        @forelse($planta as $plantas)
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3><a href="comentarios/{{ $plantas->id }}">{{ $plantas->nombre }}</a></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>{{ $plantas->descripcion }}</h4>
                @if($plantas->attachment)
                    <img src="{{ $plantas->pathAttachment() }}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" />
                @endif
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <b>Tamaño:</b> {{ $plantas->tamaño }}<br>
                <b>Flor:</b> {{ $plantas->flor }}<br>
                <b>Hoja:</b> {{ $plantas->hoja }}<br>
                <span class="pull-right"> {{ __("Comentarios") }}: {{ $plantas->comentarios->count() }} </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ __("No hay ninguna planta en este momento") }}
        </div>
        @endforelse
        @if($planta->count())
        {{$planta->links()}}
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

web.php:

```
Route::get('/images/{path}/{attachment}', function ($path, $attachment){
    $storagePath = Storage::disk($path)->getDriver()->getAdapter()->getPathPrefix();
    $imageFilePath = $storagePath . $attachment;
    if(File::exists($imageFilePath)) {
        return Image::make($imageFilePath)->response();
    }
});
```

plantas.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class plantas extends Model{
    protected $table = 'plantas';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre', 'tamaño', 'flor', 'hoja', 'descripcion', 'foto',
    ];

    public function comentarios(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comentario::class,'planta');
    }

    public function pathAttachment(){
        return "/images/planta/" . $this->attachment;
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, aun no logro que se vean las imagenes.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que me estare dejando?

Edito: Aqui teneis filesystems.php.

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),

    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),

    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        'planta' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/planta'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        ],

    ],

];
```

Más cosas: Una vez subo la imagen con mi formulario, al mirar la ruta en phpMyAdmin veo que aparece la siguiente ruta: ***C:\xampp\tmp***
Sin embargo, voy a la ruta indicada y no aparecen las imagenes. ¿Tendra que ver con mis problemas?

Tambien otro detalle. He probado a poner lo siguiente en la vista: 

**{{ $plantas->pathAttachment()}}**

Y fijaros en el resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CASI logra poner la ruta en la que actualmente guardo la imagen, pero al final ahi se quedo.

Comment: ¿Dónde están las imágenes?

Comment: @PedroPrada Esta en "\storage\app\planta".

Comment: ¿Y ya has ejecutado el comando `php artisan storage:link`que genera el link de la carpeta `public` a `storage`?

Comment: @PedroPrada ya lo he ejecutado. Tambien he ampliado la información.

Comment: no logro ver que es ´$this->attachment´ en el modelo

Comment: @Franklin'jGil'z Tampoco lo se yo. Solo se que esta en la documentación y de ahi la copie.

Comment: como Ejemplo te pongo como mando llamar mis imagenes para un perfil
`@foreach($usuario as $usu)
   <div class="card bg-light" style="width: 500">
    <img class="card-img-top img-fluid" src="/imageuser/{{ $usu->photo }}" alt="Imagen de {{ $usu->nombre }}">
   </div><br>
  
  @endforeach`

Answer (score 0):

Las imágenes las debes tener dentro de la carpeta `storage/public` directamente o dentro de cualquier carpeta que quieras dentro de `storage/public`. En tu caso, si no he entendido mal `storage/public/images/planta` y para mostrarlas:

```
<img src="{{ $plantas->pathAttachment() }}" class="img-responsive img-rounded" />
```

El framework la va a buscar a `public` directamente. Si se ha hecho el `symlink` la va a buscar a `storage/public` por lo que es en esta ruta a partir de la que debes trabajar.

Un caso similar : [como abrir una vista previa de una imagen guardada en laravel?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/121928/como-abrir-una-vista-previa-de-una-imagen-guardada-en-laravel)

Comment: Pues sigue el problema igual. He añadido más detalles al problema.

Comment: He modificado la respuesta uyea que estaba duplicando parte de la ruta porque ya la tenía  $plantas->pathAttachment()

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente las imagenes se almacenas en storage/ y no en public/ entonces con el comando `php artisan storage:link` haces que los archivos en el storage se puedan ver en public.

Basicamente lo que hace es un [symlink](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.symlink.php).